# fill an array with javascript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Say I have the following object:

`var obj = Object {izaalberg: "65", jfm: "276", matcheanauto: "981", matchfullauto: "2525", mcgoncalves: "221"…}`

I want to add the values object into array X amount of times so the result is:

```
[['izaalberg',65], ['jfm',7 ],['matcheanauto:',981],['matchfullauto',2525],['mcgoncalves',221]...];
```

Comment: just `for` loop, and i sure this duplicated question

Answer (score 2):

You need simple `for` loop like

```
var result = [];
for(var i in obj){
    result.push([i, obj[i]]);
}
```

Comment: thanks, finally I find an answers ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop, and [`Array.prototype.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

```js
var obj = {
  izaalberg: "65",
  jfm: "276",
  matcheanauto: "981", 
  matchfullauto: "2525", 
  mcgoncalves: "221"
};

var arr = [];

for (var k in obj) {
  arr.push([k, obj[k]]);
}
            
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: it's very simple thanks I find an answers ;)